# PG Grouping Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have tried the suggested solutions on similar topics but they don't work.

```
MenuItem.where(cat: s.cat).group(:subcat).find_each do |w|
```

The code above works in the development environment which uses sqlite3 but throws out the following error in the deployment environment which uses postgresql:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "menu_items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Any help on solving the issue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "menu_items.id" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Try the below query

```
MenuItem.where(cat: s.cat).group(:id, :subcat).find_each do |w|
```

Comment: @chocomousse It still gives the error? It is working for me. I'm using Postgresql too